# advice with script issues with calculator

Tags: linux, bash, calculator

I was hoping I could get some help with my script. Its a gpa calculator that spits out the average of grade point and then breaks with 99 is entered.
this is what i have so far

```
#! /bin/bash
sum=0
count=1

read -p "Enter A Grade Point: " grade
while (( $(echo "$grade != 99" | bc) )); do


    count=$(( count + 1 ))
    sum=$(echo "scale=2;($sum+$grade)" | bc)
    read -p "Enter A Grade Point: " grade
        if [[ "$grade" == 99 ]]; then
    break
        fi
    exit 1
    done
    avg=$(echo "scale=2;($sum/$count)" | bc)
         if (( avg < 4  )); then
                echo "Your GPA is $avg"
                echo "This is an B!"
         elif
            (( avg < 3  )); then
                echo "Your GPA is $avg"
                echo "This is a C!"
         elif
            (( avg < 2  )); then
                echo "Your GPA is $avg"
                echo "This is a D!"
         elif
            (( avg < 1  )); then
            echo "Your GPA is $avg"
            echo "This is a F!"
         else
            echo "Your GPA is $avg"
            echo "This is a A!"
         fi
         exit 0
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Im having an arithmetic token error when running the code and also I’m not sure where to input a break to end the loop once 99 is entered!

Comment: when you input 99, its not breaking?

Comment: Just tried it again it once I enter 99 it goes through and loop again then entering 99 once more it stops

Comment: try using the if condition just after the while loop,
    while (( $(echo "$grade != 99" | bc) )); do     <if condition here with break statment>. Check if that works

Comment: that worked! but still having an arithmethic operator error im guessing its cause its comparing bc command to an integer?

Comment: could you run the script in debug mode and paste the output.? To run in debug , you may just type     bash -x scriptname

Comment: yeah how should I post the output in debug mode on here? sorry kinda new to this

Comment: i modified your script and added as a answer. the errors should be removed now, you need to use [[ instead of (( and $var instead of var in your "if" conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have bc command to check this code, but try this.

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
count=1

read -p "Enter A Grade Point: " grade
while (( $(echo "$grade != 99" | bc) ))
do
    count=$(( count + 1 ))
    sum=$(echo "scale=2;($sum+$grade)" | bc)
    read -p "Enter A Grade Point: " grade
done
    avg=$(echo "scale=2;($sum/$count)" | bc)
         if (( $(echo "$avg 4" | awk '{print ($1 < $2)}') )); then
                echo "Your GPA is $avg"
                echo "This is an B!"
         elif
            (( $(echo "$avg 3" | awk '{print ($1 < $2)}') )); then
                echo "Your GPA is $avg"
                echo "This is a C!"
         elif
            (( $(echo "$avg 2" | awk '{print ($1 < $2)}') )); then
                echo "Your GPA is $avg"
                echo "This is a D!"
         elif
            (( $(echo "$avg 1" | awk '{print ($1 < $2)}') )); then
            echo "Your GPA is $avg"
            echo "This is a F!"
         else
            echo "Your GPA is $avg"
            echo "This is a A!"
         fi
         exit 0
```

Comment: I tried it and ill get an error "sysntax error: invalid arithmetic operator

Comment: that what i got after trying yout updated code


((: 2.16 -lt 4  : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".16 -lt 4  ")

Comment: @mncra7 try again now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
count=1
read -p "Enter A Grade Point: " grade
while [ $grade != 99 ]
do
count=$(( count + 1 ))
sum=$(echo "scale=2;($sum+$grade)" | bc)
read -p "Enter A Grade Point: " grade
echo "entered loop"
done
avg=$(echo "scale=2;($sum/$count)" | bc)
     if [[ $avg < 4  ]]
     then
     echo "Your GPA is $avg"
     echo "This is an B!"
     elif [[ $avg < 3 ]]
     then
     echo "Your GPA is $avg"
     echo "This is a C!"
     elif [[ $avg < 2  ]]
     then
     echo "Your GPA is $avg"
     echo "This is a D!"
     elif [[ $avg < 1  ]]
     then
     echo "Your GPA is $avg"
     echo "This is a F!"
     else
     echo "Your GPA is $avg"
     echo "This is a A!"
     fi
```

Not sure on the logic of the program, but the errors should be removed now. Please check